# Using Liquor for Kiddush

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shiurim-measurements, liquor-beer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimum Shi'ur for Kiddush on liquor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12069/minimum-shiur-for-kiddush-on-liquor)

Are you allowed to use other alcohols outside of wine for kiddush and how much must be used? really what i don't understand is why booze people use Shot glasses when they use wine or grape Juice the use a full cup?