# Minimum amount required to drink when making Kiddush on Liquor

Tags: shiurim-measurements, kiddush

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimum Shi'ur for Kiddush on liquor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12069/minimum-shiur-for-kiddush-on-liquor)

What is the minimum Shi'ur that one is required to consume when making Kiddush on liquor?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12069/minimum-shiur-for-kiddush-on-liquor (in case that wasn't apparent :)

Comment: I made them separate questions because this Shabbath I saw, for the first time, someone make Kiddush on liquor using a full cup, even though the cup itself was much more than a Revi'ith, which is a stringent approach, but then only drink Rov Lugmo (basically a mouthful), which is a very lenient approach. I asked him if he intended to drink Rov Kos (a majority of the cup), a stringent approach in line with the fullness of his cup, and he specifically said he was Meikel on that and specifically only drank Rov Lugmo. This made me wonder if there are sources that separate the two (three?) issues.

Comment: The real question is if there are any sources to care about rov kos by anything other than the four cups at the seder. See the shiur I linked to in my other answer about shiurim.