# Excluding water from blessing after food

Tags: halacha, blessing, bentching, shehakol-beracha

One common scenario is for someone to make a *berakha* on water at some point in the morning and to drink the water throughout the day. Suppose during the day, the person decides to have a snack whose *berakha achrona* is *borei nefashot*. While eating the snack, he continues to drink the water. After completing his snack, he wants to make a *berakha achrona*; however, he still wants to continue to drink water. Assume for the purpose of this question that throughout the entire process he is staying in one place (for example at his desk at work). Should he...

- make a *borei nefashot* and have in mind not to include the water? Then perhaps he'd be able to continue drinking without a new *berakha* (and would make another *borei nefashot* after he was done?).
- make a *borei nefashot* and then make a new *shehakol* before drinking more water?
- delay his *berakha achrona* until he has completed drinking his water?
- do something else?

Would the answer be different if--instead of a snack that requires *borei nefashot*--he had a meal with bread and would be making *birkat hamazon*?

This question is similar to [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60387/1713); the difference is that in this case the person is staying in one place rather than going somewhere else.

Comment: @DoubleAA Should I remove the part about the snack which takes a _borei nefashot_ and just leave the part about _birkat hamazon_ or do you think that is still the same question?

Comment: The case of bentching is dealt with here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18662/759 (just bentch on a kos, problem solved)

Comment: @DoubleAA The answer to that question is incomplete (unclear whether it's discussing the _b'diavad_ situation). What about when _bentching_ on a _kos_ is infeasible?

Comment: You can offer a bounty there if you want. Note bentching on a kos is not usually that unfeasible http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12069/minimum-shiur-for-kiddush-on-liquor#comment18118_5438

Comment: The answer is choice 3 since it is forbidden to make extra brochois and there is no (you did not give a)  reason to make 2 brochois in this case

Comment: The brocho (even just the desition to start it) After a meal with bread, obligates you for another first brocho, see shulchan aruch oh 179

Comment: @hazoriz A good reason to make 2 could be that if you wait till after the coffee it will be too long after the egg to bless but the coffee would have been drunk too slowly.

Comment: @DoubleAA From what I understand if there was not Brake of 72 min or he did not become hungry/thirsty again it is one "meal",  and an afterbrocho will still be nessesary (please tell me were I am wrong)